# How to separate html to 2 file by special tag in PHP

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have try to separate a html file to 2 by tag I point to.

Example

> ```
> <html>
>    <head>
>        <title>html title</title>
>    </head>
>    <body>
>        <h1>hello title</h1>
>        <p class="p2">
>          <span>here is some txt</span>
>        </p>
>        <p class="p2">
>          hello test, <a id="chp"></a>here is some txt
>        </p>
>    </body>
> </html>
> ```

If I defined the separator is **<a id="chp"></a>**. The two files should be as below

file 1:

> ```
> <html>
>    <head>
>        <title>html title</title>
>    </head>
>    <body>
>        <h1>hello title</h1>
>        <p class="p2">
>          <span>here is some txt</span>
>        </p>
>        <p class="p2">
>          hello test,
>        </p>
>    </body>
> </html>
> ```

file 2:

> ```
> <html>
>    <head>
>        <title>html title</title>
>    </head>
>    <body>
>        <h1>hello title</h1>
>        <p class="p2">
>          <span>here is some txt</span>
>        </p>
>        <p class="p2">
>          <a id="chp"></a>here is some txt
>        </p>
>    </body>
> </html>
> ```

Can anybody tell me how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `SimpleXML` library to load the html, you can then traverse through the HTML object to check each element. If you check the child nodes of each element, before moving onto the next one, for an element whose tag is `a` and has the attribute `id` = 'chp', you can break copy and remove the content after that element (until the end of the parent element), clone the SimpleXML object, then replace the entire element with the copied content from the former SimpleXML object.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your quick answer. One more question for this solution is, Is this solution have performance issue for a 2-3M html file? Sometimes maybe we have 10 more separator like that.

Comment: I am not sure as to the performance, but I believe simplexml is the best way to accomplish what you want to achieve. If you have more than 2, then you instead of breaking the function at that point, you could have it continue through until the end of the HTML, but if it is that large, you will consume a lot of memory.